# How to unlock hybris in the DB?

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud

To refresh data in a non production environment (from production) I'm sent a DB dump that I need to import, update the admin password and 'unlock' hybris - the deploy would be a lot easier if this new environment is unlocked before the deployment happens so I can do an 'update running system'. Is it possible to unlock Hybris by making changes in the database, before Hybris is started up?

Comment: Why can't you use `system.unlocking.disabled` property.

Comment: Because hybris isnt up, or even deployed im trying to alter the data in a production dump that can be used by multiple environments. If I can do it in the DB itll save a lot of time.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
update props set valuestring1='0' where name='system.locked';
```

or

```
delete from props where name='system.locked';
```

Answer (score 1):

ISSUE:

> java.lang.IllegalStateException: System update can not be performed, there is already existing lock : 'System update' on 'master' tenant and cluster id 1

SOLUTION:

NOTE -: Choose SQL query section

STEP 1:

```
select * from SYSTEMINIT;
```

STEP 2 - (Run in COMMIT mode)

```
update SYSTEMINIT set locked = 0 where clusternode = 1
```

Answer (score 0):

go to  the adminpanel console/flexiblesearch section and choose SQL query **Not flexible query** after that check if you have any DB lock by this code

```
select * from SYSTEMINIT;
```

when checking the cluster you can cluster node , and try kill the process by this code

```
delete from SYSTEMINIT where CLUSTERNODE='?YourClusterNodeNumber';
```

I hope this helps you.